# How do I properly say .999...?

Tags: terminology, decimal-expansion

I am making a video for something and I was wondering what the most optimal way to say .999...? I don't want to keep on saying .999 repeated, so what should I be saying?

Edit: I can't call it 1 as that is what the video is about(proving .999...=1)!

Comment: Say "zero dot period nine"

Comment: "point nine recurring" and "the number in question"

Comment: Give it a real name, like Johnny or Donald Trump, it will make your video funnier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zero point nine recurring. Although I think the question is not specific to 0.999.. which happens to be equal to 1. The question asks how to pronounce numbers which have numbers recurring. So 0
333.. is zero point 3 recurring.

Comment: Ok thanks, this helps out a lot!

Comment: @ThePuzzlr In my dialect I'm far more likely to say "point nine repeating" than to use "recurring", but I recognize that "recurring" is fairly common for this as well.